Teams Chat Graph API Subscription
I'm creating a subscription to teams chat using graph API in .NET core 6. I'm unsure what to be given in the EncryptionCertificate, EncryptionCertificateId, ClientState.
For EncryptionCertificate I tried giving,
1.
  certData -- //byte array from "file.cert"
  X509Certificate2 cerifikata = new(certData); //byte array from "file.cert"
  string value = Convert.ToBase64String(cerifikata.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));



    certData -- //byte array from "file.pfx"
    X509Certificate2 cert = new(certData, "pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable); 
    string value = Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));



used ngrok for the webhook
var requestBody = new Subscription
   {
       ChangeType = "created,updated,deleted",
       NotificationUrl = "https://d2.ngrok-free.app/api/notification/receive",
       LifecycleNotificationUrl= "https://d2.ngrok-free.app/api/notification/lifecycle",
       Resource = "/chats/" + chatId + "/messages",
       ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
       ClientState = "GUID",
       IncludeResourceData = true,
       EncryptionCertificate = value,
       EncryptionCertificateId = "ClientId",

   };

For EncryptionCertificateId I gave the value of ClientId used for Azure authentication
For ClientState i have given Secret value of ClientId
I have issues now in decrypting the value of notification. Exceptions like "Incorrect parameter", "Data Corrupt", "Invalid Data" are coming up. So i wanted to ensure the subscription created in the first place is correct.
Can someone confirm and help?

Is this same issue as your Aug 19 posting?  People shouldn't be giving same answers that you previously tried.  See following to setup certificate before using in your c# code  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/applications-how-to-add-certificate?tabs=http
